# Create assist touch in android

Tags: java, android, touch

Hi can you help me to create assistive floating button 
[as this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgwHS.gif)

project is here : https://github.com/Mirrorhanyu/AssistiveTouch but it is old and if i try it do not work

I haven't put any code because I want to start all over again
the manifest

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service
        android:name=".FloatingWidgetService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />
</application>
```

my main activity i allowed permission in android parameter

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION = 123;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    askForSystemOverlayPermission();
    Button button = findViewById(R.id.start);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,FloatingWidgetService.class);
            startService(intent);
        }
    });
}
private void askForSystemOverlayPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && !Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
        startActivityForResult(intent, DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION);
    }
}
```

my floatingwidgetservice , in start i add this in gradle "implementation 'com.github.andremion:counterfab:1.0.1' " for the counterfab

```
public class FloatingWidgetService extends Service {
private WindowManager mWindowManager;
private View mOverlayView;
CounterFab counterFab;
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    mOverlayView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.overlay_layout, null);
    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;        //Initially view will be added to top-left corner
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 100;
    mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    mWindowManager.addView(mOverlayView, params);
    counterFab = (CounterFab) mOverlayView.findViewById(R.id.fabHead);
    counterFab.setCount(1);
    counterFab.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        private int initialX;
        private int initialY;
        private float initialTouchX;
        private float initialTouchY;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    initialX = params.x;
                    initialY = params.y;
                    initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                    initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    float Xdiff = Math.round(event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                    float Ydiff = Math.round(event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                    params.x = initialX + (int) Xdiff;
                    params.y = initialY + (int) Ydiff;
                    mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mOverlayView, params);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: please post your code either way, this community requires a bit of effort from your side first, so it helps if we can see some code to see what you've tried and where you're struggling with specifically :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Post what have you tried pls.

Comment: i just post it but it is just start and it don't work